# Overwriting a method, during runtime, to raise an exception, on first pass only

Tags: python

I want to rewrite, during runtime, the print method of the class below so that the first pass raises an exception, but the second time it runs normally. I **cannot** change the code of the `Test` class. Assume it's in a file I don't have access to, and I cannot mock (nor use a deepcopy, since in reality I have socket objects which are not pickable).

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def print(self):
        print(f"a-> {self.a}, and b-> {self.b}")
```

I tried the following (doesn't work, with infinite recursion):

```
test_class = Test(1,2)
test_class.num_raise = 0
copy_test = test_class
def raise_exception():
    print("Inside save_clusters")
    if test_class.num_raise ==0:
        test_class.num_raise +=1
        raise Exception("save_clusters method exception")
    elif test_class.num_raise ==1:
        return copy_test.print()

test_class.print = raise_exception

try:
    test_class.print() # should raise an exception
except:
    test_class.print() # should print as normal
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making a wrapper around `Test`? You can just subclass it and override the `print` method with code from your `raise_exception` function, replacing `copy_test.print()` with `super().print()` and adding `num_raise` as a parameter.